# How to reload RecordViewForm in Salesforce lightning component?

Tags: salesforce, refresh, reload

I am using lightning:recordViewForm to load certain record from custom object in salesorce , for the first time values are populating through this form tag but I want to refresh (reload) this form to populate the latest database changes.Please see the code snippet :

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.orderWrapperList}" var="obj">
    <!-- Display details of order -->
    <lightning:card title="{!obj.Name}" iconName="standard:scan_card">


        <lightning:recordViewForm  aura:id="forceRecord" recordId="{!obj.Id}" objectApiName="Order__c">
            <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Total_Amount__c" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Score__c" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Status__c" />
            </div>
        </lightning:recordViewForm>

        <div align="center" draggable="false" >
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Cancel" onclick="{! c.reDirect }" /> 
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.openModel }" />
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: So how u want to reload it? By a button click like-click and get the newest objects from DB?

Comment: Yes the button "Submit" is doing some database commit and after that I want to show the changed values to user .

Answer (score 0):

```
refresh : function(component, event, helper) {
var action = cmp.get('c.myController');
action.setCallback(cmp,
    function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        } else {
             //do something
        }
    }
);
$A.enqueueAction(action);                                              
}
```

To refresh a view, run $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();, which reloads all data for the view.

For more Info :https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm

Comment: The above solution is loading the component again but data is not changing . May be we need to use something else to refresh 
"recordViewForm" . 
Thanks !

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you want to do or its more helpful if you share some snippet

Comment: This method reloads the entire page, not the lightning:recordViewForm